# $language->language get the de default language not current language [Drupal 7]

Tags: drupal, module, controller, drupal-7, global

I have a custom module, and on its controller, when I try to get the current interface language. I get the default language 'en'.

Someone can tell me why

```
<?php
    function module_controller_my_function(){ 
        global $language;
        var_dump($language->language);
    }
?>
```

it give the default language instead the current interface language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same issue. Nodes are translated correctly but the global $language in custom module is always the site default language.

You can get past this with some code. For example reading the language from the $_SERVER variable. Example:

```
function _my_module_get_language() {
  $referer_part_list = explode('/', $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);

  return $referer_part_list[3];
}
```

Note that most likely there is a better way of doing this (Drupal way).

Comment: In my case the issue was that I was doing an AJAX request that did not contain the language prefix. This can be resolved by passing the language information to JS or use other methods for language detection in the Drupal at admin/config/regional/language/configure.

Comment: add your solution as a answer. otherwise your answer will be marked as  not an answer.